# video player for many platform

Tags: .net, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

we have a channel tv website we want to play video on many platform like
  ipad,iphone,androied  and more..i think the best option is to use html5 player??
  that support most of this platform

you know good player that supporting this ?

another question we want to do a stream video..we brodcast live (channel tv)

thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

There's a popular solution [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The most popular video player with HTML5 support is the [JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

And yes, it supports streaming through HTTP/RTMP/RTSP/MMS

Answer (score 0):

I have used the HTML5 video tag to stream live to iPhones / iPads and it is the only option for them. However it did not appear to work for Android. Unfortunately, HTML5 video tag on desktop browsers does not support live streaming.